# Exchange 2010 - Send Connectors

Tags: exchange-2010, smtp, routing

I understand in Exchange 2010 in order to send out to the big bad Internet you require to configure a send connector to allow SMTP to *, or to your smart host etc.

My question is how does Exchange 2010 handle mail being delivered interally, i.e. to a another mailbox within Exchange, is there a send connector for this? Separate Queues in Queue Viewer for internal mail etc?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to bypass the send connector. It's deemed local delivery.

Comment: A connector connects with something else. Why would you need a connector for internal delivery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send connectors are only needed for sending SMTP email to external systems.

For internal email on the same server, or between several servers in your organization, SMTP isn't used - exchange has it's own transfer mechanisms for internal email.